# Getting error when trying to install pm2

Tags: node.js, macos

I am trying to install pm2 on my MAC OS version 10.8.5. But when i am intstalling it.

I have installed XCODE 5.1.1 on my MAC. but Even after doing that i am getting the gyp ERR! stack Error: not found: make".IS not it that GNU make comes with XCODE and was supposed to work ideally.

Please see below whole ERROR when trying to install it.

```
Rajeshs-MacBook-Pro:~ rajesh$ npm install pm2

> fsevents@0.3.1 install /Users/rajesh/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents
> node-gyp rebuild

child_process: customFds option is deprecated, use stdio instead.
-

Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please re-run as root via sudo.



gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: not found: make
gyp ERR! stack     at F (/Users/rajesh/.nvm/v0.11.14/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:43:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at E (/Users/rajesh/.nvm/v0.11.14/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:46:29)
gyp ERR! stack     at /Users/rajesh/.nvm/v0.11.14/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:57:16
gyp ERR! stack     at Object.oncomplete (evalmachine.:93:15)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 12.5.0
gyp ERR! command "node" "/Users/rajesh/.nvm/v0.11.14/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/rajesh/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v0.11.14
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@0.3.1
pm2@0.12.1 node_modules/pm2
├── ikt@0.0.0
├── json-stringify-safe@5.0.0
├── commander@2.4.0
├── eventemitter2@0.4.14
├── colors@0.6.2
├── cli-table@0.3.0
├── pidusage@0.1.0
├── cron@1.0.5
├── async@0.9.0
├── isbinaryfile@2.0.2
├── vizion@0.2.1
├── axm@0.2.24
├── shelljs@0.3.0
├── moment@2.8.4
├── debug@2.1.0 (ms@0.6.2)
├── pm2-deploy@0.1.2 (tv4@1.0.18)
├── nssocket@0.5.1 (lazy@1.0.11)
├── pm2-axon-rpc@0.3.6 (commander@1.0.5)
├── coffee-script@1.8.0 (mkdirp@0.3.5)
├── pm2-rpc-fallback@3.0.9 (axon@1.0.0, commander@1.0.5)
├── pm2-multimeter@0.1.2 (charm@0.1.2)
├── chalk@0.5.1 (escape-string-regexp@1.0.2, ansi-styles@1.1.0, supports-color@0.2.0, has-ansi@0.1.0, strip-ansi@0.3.0)
├── punt@2.2.0 (amp-message@0.1.2)
├── pm2-axon@2.0.7 (amp-message@0.1.2, escape-regexp@0.0.1, configurable@0.0.1, amp@0.3.1, debug@2.0.0)
├── pm2-logs@0.1.1 (blessed@0.0.36, pm2-interface@1.1.0, chalk@0.4.0)
└── chokidar@0.10.9 (async-each@0.1.6, readdirp@1.1.0)
```

Comment: You need to agree the XCode license. Try re-run this command with sudo. XCode command line tools has all the required build tools including make.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you need to open up Xcode and accept the user agreement first.

Secondly, while you have xcode open, you'll have to make sure you also install the command line tools: go to `Preferences` -> `Downloads` and then install `Command Line Tools`.

Answer (score 2):

As @mscdex stated "Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please re-run as root via sudo." means try open the XCode and accept the user agreement. I have similar issue while updating bower dependencies. I accepted new agreements, then it solved.

Answer (score 0):

In your `package.json`

```
"optionalDependencies": {
  "fsevents": "*"
}
```

Then do

```
npm i -f pm2
```

No more errors ; You can verify that with `npm list`